# Is it a problem to define a non-UTF8 collation in an NVARCHAR field?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on an application I need to make cross-database.

One of the things I stumbled on is that SQL Server by default has a case-insensitive collation defined, which makes queries on `NVARCHAR`/`VARCHAR` fields match on things that the application doesn't expect it to match on (i.e. case differences).

I tried to change the collation of the database to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` (as I could see that the current one was `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`). This caused a different failure because the field names were case sensitive (queries where a field was sometimes lower-case would fail when the original table definitions were all upper-case). Since it's a large application, this is not a change that can be adopted.

I have now adapted the creation scripts to add `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` to the end of all `NVARCHAR` and `VARCHAR` fields of tables. The behavior is now back to what was expected (the queries are case-sensitive). So now, the question...

Will this collation change cause any other problems I cannot see? [I can see that there are Unicode (`_UTF8`) collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#Collation_Defn). Should I add the `_UTF8` prefix for the `NVARCHAR` field or does it make no difference to simply add the normal `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` collation to all `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` fields equally?

I'm interested in the behavior of SQL Server 2012 and onwards.

Comment: >>> I can see that there are Unicode (_UTF8) collations....I'm interested in the behavior of SQL Server **2012** and onwards<<< this is starting with SQL Server **2019 (15.x)**.

Comment: So I actually cannot define a UTF8 collation without losing compatibility for version 2012. Thank you!

Comment: >>>Will this collation change cause any other problems I cannot see<<<if tempdb collation is different the code that uses temporary tables with join/comparison on string fields will fail until you use COLLATE clause